# How do I convert the (x,y) coordinates of a point on the road in its image coordinates, to its (x,y) coordinates in the world coordinates?

Tags: python, image, coordinates

I have the `(x,y)` coordinates of a marker on the road in the camera/image coordinates. I need to convert those coordinates to its corresponding world `(x,y)` coordinates assuming `z=0`.

A line of 30 pixels, 1m in front of us , might only occupy 10 pixels when it is 30 m in front of us. I mapped the values along the `y` axis of the image to their corresponding distance in meters in world space, but i do not know how to do the same for the `x` coordinate.

How would I proceed to convert the `(x,y)` in image coordinates to 3d world space, translate and rotate that point in its world coordinates, and project it back to the image plane?

Comment: I feel like we're missing a lot of context for this question. Is this computer vision? If so, are you using a library to help you? Add it as a tag! Or is this a computer graphics thing, where you're translating between different coordinate systems for rendering, but you control all the data?

Comment: Its a computer vision problem. I need to map a point on the image to its corresponding x,y on the road(assuming the road to have z=0).

Answer (score 0):

So, you may use [Merkator projection Inverse transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection#Inverse_transformations).Before using this stuff, you should define your map sizes for x and y based on the real world sizes. It's not difficult if you will playing little bit with the formulas.

Comment: Will check it out.